# facebook open graph complain explicit share not enabled even it's approved

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action

My open graph action has been approved but some facebook user will get the follow exception when I call the open graph API. Any ideas?

> OAuthException: (#100) You haven't enabled Explicitly Shared for this action type ([this is the action id]) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard

Comment: have u ticked explicit share in the app dashboard for that action?

Comment: where is that option?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the explicit sharing option through your app on Facebook. Dive into the settings for the "Action" and click on the arrow on the bottom of the page that reads "Advanced". There should be a radio button allowing you to enable explicit sharing for the specified object.